# Assign 2D list as values to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I would like to assign a 2D list as value to a dictionary, here is what I have tried

```
tags = ['a', 'b', 'c']
data = [['-' for i in range(0, 2)] for j in range(0, 2)]
table = {}
for tag in tags:
  table[tag] = data
print(table)
```

Here is what I got

```
{'a': [['-', '-'], ['-', '-']], 'b': [['-', '-'], ['-', '-']], 'c': [['-', '-'], ['-', '-']]}
```

However, when I assign new value to specific one key

```
table['a'][0][1] = 'hi'
```

All keys of [0][1] get changed as well

```
{'a': [['-', 'hi'], ['-', '-']], 'b': [['-', 'hi'], ['-', '-']], 'c': [['-', 'hi'], ['-', '-']]}
```

Anyone can point out what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Of course, *every key has been assigned **the same list***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the same reference to the same list in each value. These are just references to one list, so updating one updates everything. You need to allocate a new list in each iteration. A simple way to do this is to move the list comprehension into the loop:

```
tags = ['a', 'b', 'c']
table = {}

for tag in tags:
    # make a new list each time:
    table[tag] = [['-' for i in range(0, 2)] for j in range(0, 2)]

table['a'][0][1] = 'hi'
print(table)
```

Prints:

```
{'a': [['-', 'hi'], ['-', '-']], 'b': [['-', '-'], ['-', '-']], 'c': [['-', '-'], ['-', '-']]}
```